# Jetty WebSocket on connect, creating PIPEs which are not getting closed on termination

Tags: scala, websocket, jetty, akka, future

I am using jetty websocket client to connect to websocket server. On every successful connection it is creating around 35 file descriptors, out of 35, 32 are PIPEs. On termination these PIPEs are not getting closed.

```
class AMPWebSocketClient(remoteHost: String, remoteHandler: String) {

  val logger: Logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  //1. Create Context
  private var masterAMPClient = new WebSocketClientContext()
                                      .setTrustStore(C.GLASS_KEY_STORE)
                                      .setPassword(C.DEFAULT_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)
                                      .buildSecureClient

  private var client = createSession(remoteHost, remoteHandler)
  private var session: Session = _
  private var socket: MasterAMPFeeder = _

  private def createSession(remoteHost: String, remoteHandler: String): MasterAMPFeeder = {
    //2. Connect to WebSocket Server
      var future = ""
      var success = false
      var generatedURI: String = "wss://" + remoteHost + "/decoder/" + remoteHandler
    socket = new MasterAMPFeeder()

      do {
      try {
          masterAMPClient.getPolicy.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
          masterAMPClient.start()
          val destURI: URI = new URI(generatedURI)
          val request: ClientUpgradeRequest = new ClientUpgradeRequest()
          val future = masterAMPClient.connect(socket, destURI, request)
          logger.debug("Before connection")
          session = future.get(C.ONE_SECOND * 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          session.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
          logger.debug("Waiting for GlassDecoder to accept the connection")
            socket.getLatch().await()
          logger.debug("Connected to GlassDecoder")
      } catch {
          case e: Exception => {
            logger.debug("Not able to connect to WebSocket: {}", e.getStackTrace)
            logger.warn("Retrying to connect to: {}", generatedURI)
            Thread.sleep(10 * C.ONE_MILLISECOND)
        }
      }
      } while(socket.isNotConnected)

    return socket
  }
```

Comment: Don't know what a scala/akka PIPE is, but if its related to Java threads, then that sounds like the client defaults for the thread pool and selectors (which you don't seem to configure in your example)

Comment: How do I configure thread pool and selectors?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I tried to limit the threads private implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)). It didnt help. Its still creating around 32 PIPES